# Regex matching all lines beginning and ending with certain words and symbols

Tags: php, regex

```
#NARRATION REF.No. 322 [
    TEXT: Order No. 129,
]

#NARRATION REF.No. 323 L.NO. 5[
    TEXT: Electricity charges,
]

NARRATION L.NO. 523 [
    TEXT: Way bill no. xxx-xxx,
]

NARRATION TEXT: Edit No. xxx-xxx
```

How can all lines containing the word `NARRATION` and ending with a `[` ***on the same line*** be matched?

In this case, matches will be:

```
#NARRATION REF.No. 322 [
#NARRATION REF.No. 323 L.NO. 5 [
NARRATION L.NO. 523 [
```

The fourth one does not have a `[` and so will not match.

This is where I was before giving up: `$a = '/(NARRATION(\[*))/i';`. This matches `NARRATION`, but not anything after the word `NARRATION` and up to the `[`

Comment: Just `(NARRATION.*\[)` should do? https://regex101.com/r/zfkrbF/1

Comment: @CBroe If there's a `#` before the word `NARRATION` that needs to be included too.

Comment: Then add `#?` before the word.

Comment: Do you want `preg_match_all("/^\h*#?NARRATION.*\[$/m", $input, $lines)`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_match_all` in dot all mode:

```php
preg_match_all("/#?NARRATION.*?\](?:\r?\n|$)/s", $input, $lines);
print_r($lines[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #NARRATION REF.No. 322 [
    TEXT: Order No. 129,
    ]

    [1] => #NARRATION REF.No. 323 L.NO. 5[
    TEXT: Electricity charges,
    ]

    [2] => NARRATION L.NO. 523 [
    TEXT: Way bill no. xxx-xxx,
    ]
)
```